# can anyone help me to get expected output using Oracle SQL. .following table are “Student ”and table data are given below?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Fields:

```
Student_ID, Department, Start_Date
   ex: 
    1,A, 2017-01-1

    1,B, 2017-07-1

    1,C, 2017-12-1
```

Expected Output:

```
Student_ID, Department, Start_Date, End_Date

    ex:
 1,A, 2017-01-1, 2017-07-01

 1,B, 2017-07-1,2017-12-01

 1,C, 2017-12-1, ...
```

End_Date is the start Date of the next record for the student ID

Comment: Your question is non-readable. Could you please use code blocks inside the question, and also fix the punctuation in the topic of the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student_id,department_id, start_date,
  LEAD(start_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY start_date) AS "End_Date" 
   FROM Your_Table
```

You can use Lead() function as above

Comment: Kindly add partition by in window function.

Comment: This is close. You need a PARTITION BY on student_id and you'll need to ORDER BY the start_date, i.e. LEAD(start_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY start_date)

Comment: Thanks Kapil and Britesponge

Answer (score 0):

Give a row_number based on student_id and order by start_date. And use a join.

**Query**

```
with cte as(
  select row_number() over(    
    partition by Student_ID
    order by Start_Date asc
   ) as rn, *
  from your_table_name
)
select t1.Student_ID, t1.Department, t1.Start_Date,
t2.Start_Date as end_date
from cte t1
left join cte t2
on t1.rn = t2.rn - 1
and t1.Student_Id = t2.Student_Id;
```

**[Find demo here](http://rextester.com/PTHZ52465)**

Comment: add one more join t1.Student_ID = t2.Student_ID.

Comment: @FahadAnjum : Yeah.. added. Thank you